# Extraer dos cadenas numéricas con preg_match

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

Necesito extraer por separado los componentes de un nombre de fichero con la siguiente estructura: NombreCompleto NumTrabajador InicioTrabajo.pdf (Por ejemplo: *`Pepe Solaz Gorro 123456 01092016.pdf`*)

Estos ficheros NO siempre incluyen el tercer parámetro de fecha de inicio o el segundo parámetro de número de trabajador.
Por otro lado, el nombre puede contener espacios o guiones por ejemplo, de modo que un simple "explode" tampoco me iba a solucionar la vida.

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora, y que extrae bien tanto el nombre del trabajador como su número de trabajador, pero soy incapaz de conseguir sacar la fecha.

```
//ejemplo de variable inicial
$path = "path1/path2/Pepe Solaz Gorro 123456 01092016.pdf"

//separamos por /
$partes = explode("/", $path);

$var1 = $partes[0];
$var2 = $partes[1];
$fichero = utf8_encode($partes[2]);

//extraemos el numero de trabajador
preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $fichero, $ntrab);
```

Hasta donde he sido capaz de entender, preg_match,si le ponemos el tercer parámetro (`$ntrab` en este caso) debería recoger en un array todas las coincidencias que encuentre con la condición, en este caso cualquier número entre 0 y 9, por lo que entiendo que `$ntrab[0]` debería contener 123456 01092016, `$ntrab[1]` 123456 y `$ntrab[2]` 01092016 pero estoy segura de que lo he entendido mal yo, porque no logro sacar el **01092016** de la cadena inicial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando la función `preg_match_all` puedes obtener ambas cadenas numéricas con la aproximación que has usado en tu ejemplo, da un array multidimensional con todas las coincidencias.

```
//ejemplo de variable inicial
    $path = "path1/path2/Pepe Solaz Gorro 123456 01092016.pdf";

    //separamos por /
    $partes = explode("/", $path);

    $var1 = $partes[0];
    $var2 = $partes[1];
    $fichero = utf8_encode($partes[2]);

    //extraemos el numero de trabajador
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+/', $fichero, $ntrab);

echo $ntrab[0][0]."-".$ntrab[0][1]; //123456-01092016
```

Comment: Gracias !!! Con tu propuesta (ligeramente modificada) he logrado lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias @Carmen

Comment: No hay de que, para eso estamos

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con:

```
preg_match('/([^0-9]+)([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)/', $fichero, $results);
```

Los resultados los tendrás en la variable $results, la cual será un array que quedará así:

```js
[ 'Pepe Solaz Gorro', '123456', '01092016' ]
```

Y si no tenemos duda de la longitud en dígitos de los campos numéricos (con la fecha no debería haberla) podemos fijar la posición especificándola:

```
preg_match('/([^0-9]+)([0-9]{6})\s([0-9]{8})/', $fichero, $results);
```

Comment: El problema que veo es que de esta manera, si el nombre del fichero incluye tanto el numero de trabajador como la fecha inicio, el resultado sale bien, porque $results[2] y $results[3] contienen el numtrabajador y fecha inicio respectivamente, pero si alguno de esos dos parámetros falta, $results[2] puede tomar el valor correcto (numtrabajador) o el incorrecto (fechainicio)

Comment: Todo se puede hacer con expresiones regulares... he ampliado la respuesta ;)